# How to use my Windows UPN login name for WiFi authentication?

Tags: windows, active-directory, wifi, login

When I connect to a WiFi network, I can set through GPO to automatically use my Windows credentials for login. The transmitted logon name format is **DOMAIN\username**. Is it possible somehow to use the users **UPN** for the WiFi login?

We use a radius server for authentication to the WiFi, and until now the authentication with the Windows logon name worked well. Now we have the necessity to login with our e-mail address. The e-mail corresponds to the UPN, which is set in AD for each user, as well as the "old-style" logon format DOMAIN\username.
I tried to login onto the computer (Win10, AD 2016) with my UPN and it works, but the WiFi connection still transmits the "old-style" logon name and not my UPN.
Is it possible to achieve this on the Windows/GPO side?

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: We have the same Problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry. Maybe we change to authentication with certificates.